# What are some benefits from having multiple SharePoint Sites within an organization?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sub-site

I'm helping to design a large SharePoint implementation (300+ users over multiple branches), and the powers that be are wanting to create individual SharePoint Sub-Sites for each department and various groups we have. What are of the benefits to having multiple Sites rather than pages? Are there any negatives to doing this way?

This is a SharePoint 2013 Online, This is an ootb implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some key factors that come to mind.

- Content Separation - Separation of content using different content databases. Creating different site collections will give you the option to use a separate content database. This comes in handy for migration, upgrading, and overall maintenance of SharePoint
- Permission Level - Using site collections will allow a completely different permission level for each site. The general rule of thumb is only uninherit permissions if you absolutely have to.
- Relevancy - Only shows content that is important to the person from that site/department/location, etc.
- Security - You don't want to have 5 administrators on content that isn't theirs. They don't know who should have access to what. Most likely administrators from that site/location/department will have an idea who should access what content.

You can imagine the negatives that each positive can make. Some are convenience over security. Others are reusability over content separation.